# Why can't LocalDateTime be obtained from a feasible temporal accessor?

Tags: java, datetime, parsing

I am using the same [pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns) to both format and parse a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) object. However, parsing the formatted string is throwing a [`DateTimeParseException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeParseException.html). I created this [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to demonstrate the issue:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss:nn");
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.of(2023, 1, 12, 10, 2, 7, 0);
String formatted = formatter.format(dateTime);
System.out.println(formatted);
LocalDateTime.parse(formatted, formatter);
```

The output is:

```
01-12-2023 10:02:07:00
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '01-12-2023 10:02:07:00' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {MicroOfSecond=0, SecondOfMinute=7, HourOfAmPm=10, MilliOfSecond=0, NanoOfSecond=0, MinuteOfHour=2},ISO resolved to 2023-01-12 of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(DateTimeFormatter.java:1920)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1855)
    at java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)
    at com.nhbb.router.drawing.DrawingManager.main(DrawingManager.java:45)
Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {MicroOfSecond=0, SecondOfMinute=7, HourOfAmPm=10, MilliOfSecond=0, NanoOfSecond=0, MinuteOfHour=2},ISO resolved to 2023-01-12 of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.time.LocalDateTime.from(LocalDateTime.java:461)
    at java.time.format.Parsed.query(Parsed.java:226)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain LocalTime from TemporalAccessor: {MicroOfSecond=0, SecondOfMinute=7, HourOfAmPm=10, MilliOfSecond=0, NanoOfSecond=0, MinuteOfHour=2},ISO resolved to 2023-01-12 of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.time.LocalTime.from(LocalTime.java:409)
    at java.time.LocalDateTime.from(LocalDateTime.java:457)
    ... 4 more
```

Looking at other answers on this site, it seems like this only should happen if a required temporal field is missing, such as year or month. All the required fields are present in the `java.time.format.Parsed` instance shown in the output, so why is this code not working?

Comment: Your issue is with the hours part, if you change `hh` to `HH` it should work.

Comment: @YoucefLAIDANI I accidentally used a 12 hour clock instead of a 24 hour clock. Such a simple mistake!

Comment: Also I can’t believe that `:nn` in your format pattern is what you want. `n` is for nanoseconds, billionths of seconds. If you wanted 100ths of seconds, you need `SS`.

Comment: A feasible `TemporalAccessor`? You need more scrutiny when reading the exception message: *TemporalAccessor: {…, HourOfAmPm=10, …}…*

Comment: Since you were using a 12-hour clock, and didn't include any AM/PM information, the hour number is ambiguous when parsing (i.e., is `2` for hours 2 AM or 2 PM?). As you've discovered, using a 24-hour clock fixes this ambiguity, but I believe so would including AM/PM information in the pattern.

Comment: @Slaw yes, I could also use am/pm in my pattern by adding `a`. It's frustrating that I had this issue because I was discussing the time format with my other team members before I started this project, and we all agreed on using a 24 hour clock. I just got so comfortable in my rhythm that I completely forgot when it came to setting the time format.